# Let $f:R\to R$ be a differential function satisfying $f(\frac{x+y}{3})=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3}$ for all real $x$ and $y$..

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

> Let $f:R\to R$ be a differential function satisfying $f(\frac{x+y}{3})=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3}$ for all real $x$ and $y$ and $f’(2)=2$. If $g(x)=|f(|x|)-3|$ for all $x\in R$, then number of non differentiable points of $g(x)$ is?

$$f’(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(\frac {3x+3h}{3}) - f(\frac{3x-0}{3})}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(3h)-f(0)}{3h}=f’(0)$$

How do I proceed from this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating w.r.t $x$ we get $\frac  1 3 f'(\frac {x+y} 3) =\frac {f'(x)} 3$. Since this holds for all $y$ we see that $f'$ is a constant. Hence $f(x)=ax+b$ for some constants  $a$ and $b$. $f'(2)=2$ gives $a=2$. Thus $f(x)=2x+b$. Also putting $x=y=0$ in the given equation we get $f(0)=2$. Thus $f(x)=2x+2$. Can you finish?

[The answer is $3$].

Comment: Why is $f’$ constant that exactly?

Comment: Given any $x$ and $z$ take $y=3z-x$ to see that $f'(z)=f'(x)$. @Aditya

Comment: Can we say that since $f’(0)=f’(x)$, $f’(x)$ is constant?

Comment: @Aditya I have proved that $f'(\frac  {x+y} 3)=f'(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$. I am sure you can put $y=3x-z$ in this to get $f'(x)=f'(z)$ **for all real numbers** $x$ and $z$. Doesn't that say that $f'$ is constant?